# Positive lookbehind not working as expected

Tags: .net, regex

I have a little problem matching strings using *.ne*t regular expressions. 
For example I have the following string:

> II Kop 15 / 1544

And I want to match the second number following the */* character. 
Additionally I only want to match that number when there is a preceding number followed by a slash. Also this number must only be 2 or 4 digits.

I came up with something like this:

> (\b[0-9]{2}\b|\b[0-9]{4}\b)

It matches 2 or 4 digit numbers , as it matched here 15 and 1544.
Now I'm trying positive lookbehind:

> (\b[0-9]{2}\b|\b[0-9]{4}\b)(?<=(\b[0-9]{0,10}\b)\s*(/)\s*)

Not match. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler to place the look behind before your capturing group.

```
(?<=[0-9] / )([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})
```

Variable length look-behind is allowed in .NET, so you can also write the regex as:

```
(?<=[0-9]\s*/\s*)([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes -> i had to place lookbehind before expression. No - ,net regex support inifnite width lookbehind and after replacing it actually works. I mark this as answer, because it helped me.

Comment: `Second, you can't use + * ? {}` .NET allows variable length look-behind.

Comment: Avoid using `\d` unless you want to match digits in Unicode. Short hand character class `\s`, `\d`, `\w` matches Unicode character in .NET

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I wasn't aware that .NET supports variable length look-behind. Why \d match Unicode numbers \U4324 like this. could you show me some URL for this? (I'm not a programmer however I would like to understand the reasons behind). Finally: putting look behind after some string where the look-behind match is surely before the matched string will takes much longer to run even it can't feel in most cases. Same with zero times (*), I like to avoid it whenever I can for faster run + involving some other logic where it is possible.